# Images On The Description Of An RSS Item

Tags: xml, image, rss

I'm starting with RSS development, for my new site, but I want to know if there is any way to put images on the description of a item, something like this:

```
<item>
    <title>Image Test</title>         
    <link>http://testin.test</link>
    <description>Some text...
    <img src="image.jpg"></description>
</item>
```

And if it's possible, which feed readers will be able to visualize it clearly and perfect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can have a reference to an image inside CDATA (which is typically done).  Example:

```
<item><title>June 13  : Cool Clear Waters</title>
<link>http://www.whitegrass.com/report.html</link>
<description>
<![CDATA[<img align="left" hspace="5" src="http://www.whitegrass.com/June 2011/IMGP9201LG.jpg"/>
 Work a little, play a little, dream into summer, celebrate a great winter gone by, keep movin'... <br />]]>
</description>
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.mcgurrin.com/whitegrass.xml</guid>
<pubDate>Tue, 14 Jun 2011 01:32:00 GMT</pubDate></item>
```

An alternative is that one reference (which may be to an image) is allowed in the enclosure tag in RSS 2.0 (see the specification for details, as additional information must be provided. More typically this is used to link to the mp3 for podcasts.