# is there some standard of xml tag for thumbnail in rss?

Tags: xml, rss

In my blog I provide RSS. I would like to provide url to photo thumbnail for each post.

Is there some standardised tag for providing thumbnail image link for each post accepted by wide spectrum of RSS readers?

Answer (score 2):

My research thus far seems to suggest "No."

This is a good question. After looking everywhere myself, I've seen variations of these  methods for incorporating thumbnails into an RSS feed item:

- Embed as HTML directly into `<description>` tag (e.g. [Images On The Description Of An RSS Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208873/images-on-the-description-of-an-rss-item)). This seems to be the most commonly used technique.
- Incorporate it into the `<media:thumbnail url="..." />` tag
- Incorporate it into the `<media:content url="..." type="image/jpeg" />` tag
- Let the reader figure it out on it's own, e.g. via commonly used OpenGraph standards (like Feedly seems to do)

And to top it off, it all depends on the specific reader if it will be displayed or not.